# Adding new parameters for a procedure in SQL Server for a report in SSRS

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I need help creating new parameters for my current procedure here are the description for what I need to add in my procedure after that I will add it to my SSRS report.

We need some revisions to the "Label Generic Serial Numbers" report:

- New Parameters to add to those currently there -

  - Material Code - five characters
  - Lot Date (YYMMDD)
  - Weight in pounds (lbs) (even lbs, two digits, no decimal)
- The resulting barcode will need to be 44 characters with the following inserted:

  - Material Code from parameter beginning at character 11 ending at character 15
  - Lot Date from parameter beginning at character 19 ending at character 24
  - Weight from parameter beginning at character 30 ending at character 31

This report should produce serial numbers that are 44 characters long with the Material Code, Net Weight, and Lot in the correct places to scan using barcode receiving.

Here is my current procedure that works for my report:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[NewLabelGeneratorGeneric]
(
        @quantity int = 1,
        @length int = 44,
        @prefix varchar(6),
        @material int = 5,
        @lotDate int = 6,
        @netWeight int = 4
)

AS

DECLARE @projectId int = NULL,
        @order varchar(max) = NULL,                    
        @lineNumber int = NULL

DECLARE @suffix varchar(4)

DECLARE @labels TABLE (id int, label varchar(max), number varchar(max))

DECLARE @labelId int,
        @label varchar(max),
        @counter int

DELETE FROM @labels

IF @length > 80
SET @length = 80

SET @counter = 1

WHILE @counter <= @quantity
BEGIN

RETRYLABEL:

EXEC datex_footprint.Identities_GetNextId 'Label', @labelId OUTPUT

SELECT @label = ISNULL(@prefix,'')
                + RIGHT('00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
                + RIGHT(11, @material + 19, @lotDate + 29, @netWeight)
                + CONVERT(varchar(max),@labelId),ISNULL(@length,LEN(@labelId)))
                + ISNULL(@suffix,'')

IF EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM datex_footprint.LicensePlates LP WITH (NOLOCK)
            WHERE LP.archived = 0
            AND LP.lookupCode = @label)
BEGIN
GOTO RETRYLABEL
END

INSERT INTO @labels (id, label, number)
SELECT  @counter AS id,
        @label AS label,
        CONVERT(varchar(max),@counter) + ' of ' + CONVERT(varchar(max),@quantity) AS number

SET @counter = @counter + 1

END

SELECT          L.id as Id,
                L.label as Label,
                L.number as Squence
FROM @labels L
```

Comment: Were you going to try this yourself first? Or, not really?

Comment: yes that is my procedure I created and now I need to add the other parameters

Comment: Okay, excellent, then do just that. If you created the procedure in the first place, then you have the skills to change it, right? What are you expecting here?

Comment: Just  a guidance to what would be the best way to add those new parameters I am not expecting you to write the code, but I am open to suggestions is that bad?

Comment: You won't be banned for asking for advice, but we prefer to help people solve problems/issues they have. Asking for an opinion on how to do something *is* considered off topic, however. You should try to solve this on your own. If you run into a specific issue while making your changes, come back and let us know about it.

Comment: Add the new parameters to the stored procedure. Then refresh your dataset in design mode to bring in the new parameters into the report. FWIW, this looks like homework to me.

Comment: Okay I will add the parameters to my new procedure and if I run to issues I will let you guys know, and its not homework is a project.

Comment: Guys I added new changes to the procedure for the new parameters I need based on my description. can you guys help me here?

Comment: I found that the only thing I am missing is to add the logic of my three new parameters in the select @label table, if I add those correctly then that should do it,

Comment: can you guys let me know the best way to add my three new parameters with my logic to the @label select statement?

Comment: I was able to fix my issue